# Error on installing cordova

Tags: cordova

Getting below error while installing cordova in linux

I have enter below command in cmd :

`sudo npm install -g cordova`

Getting below error :

```
npm ERR! Error: invalid version: 3001.0001.0000-dev-harmony-fb    
npm ERR!     at validVersion (/usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:573:40)    
npm ERR!     at final (/usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:323:23)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:139:33
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/nodejs/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:251:40
npm ERR!     at fs.js:268:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/srtpl13/Sites/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd /home/srtpl13/Sites
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/srtpl13/Sites/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question and use the editor's code formatting feature to clearly distiguish a machine output from a regular text.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your internet connection or ping via CMD.

Comment: There is no problem in inernet connection bro.